# Why did mirror-image life not evolve?

Tags: biology, chirality

[Mirror life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_life) is a hypothetical form of life with mirror-reflected molecular building blocks. For instance, a mirror virus RNA would be constructed with left-handed sugars.

Why do we see absolutely no mirror life? Would we expect extraterrestrial life to perhaps be mirrored? If we molecularly constructed a mirror sperm and egg, could we theoretically make a human immune to every virus?

Comment: The chiral nature of the weak force may ultimately be responsible:https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/weak-nuclear-force-shown-to-give-asymmetry-to-the-biochemistry-of-life/.   I had remembered reading this when I came across your question. Also, If a person was mirror to life on earth, my understanding is that they'd have to be fed mirror based food as well, which would be problematic.

Comment: Why do you think there's a physics answer to this, any more than there is a physics answer to "why did no humans with six arms evolve?"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I think there is a physics answer to this (see above link) organic molecules from space also tend to be "handed" one way

Comment: @R.Rankin that's fascinating. Thank you.

Comment: Here on Earth, amino acids are left handed, sugars are right handed, so I'm unclear how the weak force makes one left and the other right...

Comment: @R.Rankin talk about "fine tuning"....

Comment: I think this would be more of a Biology Stack Exchange type question than a Physics Stack Exchange one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there physical reasons for breaking this symmetry in biological systems?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/630735/)

Comment: Life is basically a sequence of symmetry breaking events (many of these symmetries are more complex than chirality), see, e.g., Anderson's [More is different](https://www.tkm.kit.edu/downloads/TKM1_2011_more_is_different_PWA.pdf)

Comment: @Jon_Custer  "That is that both L-amino acids and D-sugars are slightly more stable then their opposites."   Granted this difference is apparently very small. https://www.google.com/amp/s/phys.org/news/2014-10-handedness-life.amp

Answer (score -4):

Chirality of life may need antimatters world. I am no expert in biology. In physics, time need to be inverse I believe for antimatters to exist. There is a need for separation between. Other than black holes, it might be impossible for antimatters or chiral life to exist, if life have same issue. Chirality deals more to physic, I agree on this.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as references to supporting literature.